# Web api with .NET Core 3.1 does not load fonts .ttf when deploying on Azure Linux

Tags: c#, linux, azure, .net-core, path

I am facing a problem regarding my deployed web app on linux.

the following code can not load the appropriate fonts

```
 XPdfFontOptions options = new XPdfFontOptions(PdfFontEncoding.Unicode);

 XFont fontBig = new XFont(Path.Combine(_rootPath + "//Content//fonts//Roboto-Light"), 30, XFontStyle.Regular, options);
 XFont fontRegular = new XFont(Path.Combine(_rootPath + "//Content//fonts//Roboto-Light"), 20, XFontStyle.Regular, options);
```

I know that the path should be case-sensitive as it is. please check the path below of the font in the deployed wwwroot folder of the web app.

[image]

Please note that images could be loaded using some paths, but not the fonts.

Could this be related to pdf sharp? or is it some problem with linux config?

in case I switch to windows (localhost) or any windows web app on azure it works fine and fonts are working, however I want to go with linux mainly for cost reduction.

p.s I also tried the paths using ".ttf" at the end without any success

Comment: Is the first argument to XFont constructor really a path? Looks more like a family name to me from what I see [around the web](https://github.com/Lakerfield/PdfSharp/blob/master/PDFsharp/code/PdfSharp/PdfSharp.Drawing/XFont.cs) (it's PdfSharp, right?).. Have you actually installed the fonts in your linux instance, or have you just dropped them on disk?

Comment: I haven't yet found an example that puts a path in the first arg; they all seem to be names of as-installed fonts, [for example on PdfSharp site](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/(X(1)S(xhsdqhv013mhhehcmxmhmpsk))/HelloWorld-sample.ashx)

Comment: actually, I am not running on any VM, I am just running Linux in an Azure web app instance (PaaS). I am not sure if I can install any font there. I just dropped the fonts into the folder as you can see in the screenshot. That was working with windows

Comment: Have a read of http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/FontResolver-sample.ashx - it appears that using your custom font family name is a matter of providing a class that implements these two methods, one of which I figute will read the font off disk and return it as bytes when pdfsharp asks for it